Questions that should be directed to customer service of service providers should be off topic
Questions like these:
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/45969/lost-my-blockchain-wallet-id-and-my-email-account-has-been-hacked-i-do-not-have
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/45945/trouble-with-kraken-exchange
should be closed and marked as off-topic. However, there is no selectable off-topic reason for questions like these. The closest one is : 
"Questions seeking product or service reviews are off-topic because they tend to attract subjective, low-quality, and spam answers. On the other hand, offerings in the Bitcoin space are still evolving rapidly which often renders answers outdated quickly"
Not sure how exactly it should be phrased but there should be a selectable off topic reason that states that questions that are better directed at customer service representatives of service providers should not be posted here.

I'd love to declare these types of posts as off-topic, but they are really not that much different than questions like "How do I set value X in wallet Y?".  When the problem is password/account recovery, then I agree they should be off-topic.  But when the problem is about how to use software, whether web based or app based, I feel they have a place here.

I agree with Jestin , and I think Murch a good solution that will not include "how to use" types of questions as off topic

That's a great suggestion.
How about:

Questions seeking help for restoring user accounts or other matters concerning your customer relationship with a company should be directed at the respective customer service.
  Please understand that we have no insights into such matters and therefore consider them as off-topic.

Improvement suggestions welcome. :)

This is now live.
